# Debugging chunked world tile misalignment

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine

I've got a kink somewhere in my code, hopefully someone sees what I'm missing;

I'm in the process of compartmentalizing my world into chunks, each tile has a sprite, chunk_position and chunk_offset component, being defined as such:

```cpp
/**
 * @brief Represents the position of a chunk within the world relative to other chunks.
 *
 * The chunk position specifies the coordinates (x, y) of a chunk within the world. Each chunk is a
 * 32x32 array of tiles, and the chunk position ranges between (0, 0) and (255, 255).
 */
struct chunk_position
{
    i8 x = 0;
    i8 y = 0;
};

/**
 * @brief Represents the offset of a tile within a chunk.
 *
 * The chunk offset specifies the position of a tile within a chunk. The offset ranges between
 * (0, 0) and (31, 31) and is relative to the bottom-left corner of the chunk.
 */
struct chunk_offset
{
    i8 x = 0;
    i8 y = 0;
};
```

Now, consider this world gen and render code:

```cpp
void sandbox_scene::create_chunked_demo_world() noexcept
{
    log::info("sandbox_scene::create_chunked_demo_world");

    FastNoise::SmartNode<> const fn_generator = FastNoise::NewFromEncodedNodeTree("CgACAAAAAAAAAAAAAIA/");

    entity const camera_entity = create_entity();
    detail::create_and_configure_camera_entity(camera_entity);

    std::vector<f32> noise_map(4194304);
    fn_generator->GenUniformGrid2D(noise_map.data(), 0, 0, 2048, 2048, 0.15F, 1339);
    clamp_noise_values(noise_map);
    std::reverse(noise_map.begin(), noise_map.end());

    auto const total_chunks = static_cast<const fl::usize>(64 * 64);
    auto const chunk_size   = static_cast<const fl::usize>(32 * 32);

    for (usize chunk_index = 0; chunk_index < total_chunks; chunk_index++)
    {
        i8 const chunk_x = static_cast<i8>(chunk_index % 64);
        i8 const chunk_y = static_cast<i8>(chunk_index / 64);

        for (usize chunk_offset_index = 0; chunk_offset_index < chunk_size; chunk_offset_index++)
        {
            i8 const chunk_offset_x = static_cast<i8>(chunk_offset_index % 32);
            i8 const chunk_offset_y = static_cast<i8>(chunk_offset_index / 32);

            entity tile_entity = create_entity();
            tile_entity.add_component<struct chunk_position>(chunk_x, chunk_y);
            tile_entity.add_component<struct chunk_offset>(chunk_offset_x, chunk_offset_y);

            f32 const noise_value = noise_map.back();
            noise_map.pop_back();
            glm::vec4 const colour = get_colour_for_value(noise_value);

            sprite* sprite_component        = &tile_entity.add_component<struct sprite>();
            sprite_component->texture       = nullptr;
            sprite_component->tint_color    = colour;
            sprite_component->tiling_factor = 1.0F;
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
m_current_scene->m_registry.view<struct sprite, struct chunk_position, struct chunk_offset>().each([](auto, struct sprite& sprite, struct chunk_position& position, struct chunk_offset& offset) {
    f32 const absolute_x = static_cast<f32>(position.x) * 32.0F + static_cast<f32>(offset.x);
    f32 const absolute_y = static_cast<f32>(position.y) * 32.0F + static_cast<f32>(offset.y);

    glm::vec3 const translation = {absolute_x, absolute_y, 0.0F};
    glm::mat4 const transform   = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0F), translation);

    renderer_2d::draw_sprite(transform, sprite);
});
```

And finally the output image, which clearly shows that the tiles are being rendered out of alignment. I feel like my logic is sound, but there's obviously a bug somewhere but I can't quite put my finger on it. The noise data should be correct, as my former approach is working just fine with the exact same data. Any help is appreciated. The second image shows how it's supposed to look like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the first thing you should do is simplify geometry.  Like single vertical and horizontal lines, maybe even a squares in the corners, etc.  Simply looking at code is often many times harder than knowing where the problem is from symptoms.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'll give that a shot, hopefully that'll show what's wrong :thumbsup:

Comment: The other thing I find can be useful is to put a box around chunk 1, then around chunk 2, etc.  Like, colour the outer pixels of it (or fill it in completely).  Debugging graphics math is really annoying in my experience.  Good luck.